# Closable tab in kendo ui

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I looked carefully through [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tabstrip), but could not find something that is so popular and extremely useful in many other libraries - I mean closable tabs. I wish there was something like:

```
$("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
    dataTextField: "Name",
    dataContentField: "Content",
    dataSource: [
      { Name: "Tab1", Content: "Tab2: content", closable: true  } // <-- this is what I want
    ]
});
```

But, unfortunatelly. I could not find anything similar to that, but I hope some easy solution (without a lot of funky css and js stuff) exists.

Comment: I wish something like in a much more primitive library - http://www.primefaces.org/primeui/#tabview

Comment: Judging by this - http://www.telerik.com/forums/issues-with-dynamically-openned-tabs-and-closing-it there are only some hacky solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here is a quick demo I have knocked up for you.

[Closable tabs in Kendo](http://dojo.telerik.com/iRisE)

Essentially I have done two things:

1) Add a span tag with a data attribute indicating the index of the tab

```
<div id="tabstrip">
    <ul>
      <li>Tab 1 <span style="border:1px solid red;" data-tab="0">*</span></li>
      <li>Tab 2 <span  style="border:1px solid red;" data-tab="1">*</span> </li>
    </ul>
    <div>Content 1</div>
    <div>Content 2</div>
</div>
```

2) Added a click event to the span tags to remove the tab and then re-sequence the tab number.

```
   var tabStrip = $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip().data("kendoTabStrip");

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("span[data-tab]").on('click',function(e){
      //indicate I am removing a tab
      console.log("removing tab::");

      //find the tab I am removing based on click
      var tabIndex = $(this).data("tab"); 

      //show tab index 0 positioned
      console.log(tabIndex); 

      //remove tab. 
      tabStrip.remove(tabIndex );

      //now find any remaining tabs and reindex them. 
      var reIndex = $("span[data-tab]"); 
      console.log(reIndex);
      if(reIndex !== null && reIndex !== undefined && reIndex.length > 0 )
      {
        var counter = 0; 
        reIndex.each(function(item){
          $(this).data('tab',counter);
          counter++; 
        });
      }

    }); 

  });
```

Hopefully this is the sort of thing you are looking for with kendo.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I only wish `tabStrip.remove` reindexed tabs itself :)

Comment: I guess the question is why have closable tabs? Is it the most suitable control for this specific "use case"? It maybe something to suggest as a feature request via the kendo user voice.

Comment: To have closable tabs is an abvious requirement in an innumerable ammount of applications/systems.

Comment: In the types of applications I build it's not an obvious feature for me. I am sure there are lots of cases where this can be useful so I wasn't discounting it as a feature. As I said for me it's not a "go to" feature that I would use. Glad the demo helped. If you need any further info/changes then feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: Browsers have closable tabs, many more other data-driven applications where users interact with different data grids also need closable tabs (to have an infinite tabstrip with all grid tables is not reasonable) and the list goes on. So, for me it's a highly important feature. And thanks for demo :)